# console hangs during property verification with nuXmv

Tags: model-checking, nuxmv

I am using nuXmv to develop a model, Where I want to initialize 3 of the variables as a range of integers and not fixed integer value. The values are - 1..100, 20..100 and 0..200

> the model simulation for a fixed set of init values works as expected and also the properties can be verified.
>
> However, when I feed with a range of init values to be randomly chosen, the model hangs indefinitely.

Does any one know what could be the reason and how to solve this?

Comment: **1.** would you be able to share the `smv` model? **2.** did you try progressively enlarging the size of the range of values from something reasonably small (1-3 values) to the larger domain? What was the result of that?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I checked progressively for different combinations of ranges and was lucky to find that for a specific combination of init values, there was more than 1 valid TRANS constraints, after which the system could not decide which one to proceed with. After handling that situation, now its runs for the complete range, but is slow.
However, I had the assumption that it should have non-deterministically chosen one transition and continued, but this is obviously not happening.

Comment: that's indeed the case, but unless you share your model it is hard for me to provide any suggestion

Comment: @PatrickTrentin, I am afraid I cannot share the model. I will see if I can replicate this with another example and share that